# Position div according to a specific responsive area

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a responsive layout, and I've separated an element form it's background image, so I can animate it as a div.

Now, I need to place the div in it's position again while resizing the browser. In other words, I need it to be scaled correctly with the background as I didn't separate them.

How to set the div using CSS or jQuery? please advise.

Kindly be noted that the background should fill the background, so I've set it's size to Cover `background-size: cover`. Also, I must set the element to be a div with data, because in the actual project it contains text as well.

CSS:

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-image: url('http://www.zhealthywealthy.com/bg.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.element_to_be_ajdusted {
    /* width: 304px; 304px = 22.045% of the background size "1333px"*/
    width: 22.045%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="element_to_be_ajdusted">
        <img src="http://www.zhealthywealthy.com/rat.png" />
    </div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kb8kjbrx/3/

Comment: _Now, I need to place the div in it's position again_. Can you explain more on this?

Comment: Your images aren't rendering in the fiddle, so it's a little difficult to see how they're supposed to relate to one another.

Comment: @benjarwar are you sure that the images aren't rendering? they appears on my device correctly!

Comment: Quite sure: http://jsfiddle.net/kb8kjbrx/2/

Comment: @GuruprasadRao the image position and the dashed area that the image should be placed in before I separate them. check out the fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly (and I'm not sure that I am), you want the image in `.element_to_be_ajdusted` (sic) to be placed directly over the center of the background image on the body. So really, you just need a little CSS to horizontally and vertically center the `<div>` and its child `<img>`. I think? Right?

```
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.element_to_be_ajdusted {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Forked your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hLm8109n/

**Update**

So you need it to scale? Well that's going to be tricky, since you're setting the body background image to `background-size: cover`, which means when the window exceeds the size of the source background image, the image is going to be scaled up. Determining that breakpoint seems tricky and fruitless, especially if you ever need to change the background image.

It looks like you just want to fill the background with color, since you're using a pretty large source image. So, for starters, can you remove the `background-size: cover` declaration and add a `background-color` that matches your image?

Then, you could also just set the `.element_to_be_ajdusted` image as a background image instead of using an `<img>` tag, and center it over the `body`'s background image.

HTML:

```
<div class="element_to_be_ajdusted"></div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #606060;
    background-image: url('http://www.zhealthywealthy.com/bg.png');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.element_to_be_ajdusted {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://www.zhealthywealthy.com/rat.png');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Revised fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hLm8109n/3/

Comment: Just a cut and paste error. Correct fiddle now linked above.

Comment: No, I need it to get the same offset and the width for the dashed area, while the area is in changing according to the browser size.

Comment: I need it to be scaled correctly with the background

Comment: Basically, I've cut a part from an image, and I need to place it again on the same area on the browser. In case of the background should be responsive to the browser size. You got it?

Comment: Sort of, but it seems like you're making things a lot more difficult than they need to be. I think you should rethink exactly what you're trying to do. See my **Update** above.